# Find MAX expiration date and also a subscription plan but only return one row with max expiration date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am building a stored procedure to query a subscription table to find when an expiration date is approaching, such as a week from now. There are multiple subscription plans so I need a single row returned per PlanType with its max expiration date. The query I built is giving me multiple records where the expiration date is greater than the date queried.

Here is the result I'm getting, notice rows 2 and 3 are the same PlanType of "3" and I only want to return the one with the latest expiration date as I'm comparing that with "today" to see if it's within 7 days of today.

```
SubscriptionId  AccountID   PlanType    Expiration  IsVerified  IsCanceled  IsActive
174322  5025132 2   2025-01-21 23:59:59.000 1   0   1
167756  5025132 3   2024-02-05 00:00:00.000 1   0   1
172026  5025132 3   2025-02-05 00:00:00.000 1   0   1
```

Here is my SQL.

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
       SubscriptionId,
       AccountID,
       PlanType,
       MAX(ExpiresUtc) AS Expiration,
       --PendingExpiration7DayReminderSent,
       IsVerified,
       IsCanceled,
       IsActive
FROM dbo.Subscriptions
GROUP BY SubscriptionId,
         PlanType,
         AccountID,
         PendingExpiration7DayReminderSent,
         IsVerified,
         IsCanceled,
         IsActive
HAVING (
    --(MAX(ExpiresUtc) < DATEADD(d, 14, GETUTCDATE()))
    --AND 
    --(
    MAX(ExpiresUtc) > DATEADD(d, 7, GETUTCDATE())
       --)
       )
       AND
       (
           --(PendingExpiration7DayReminderSent = 1)
           --AND 
           (IsVerified = 1)
           AND (IsCanceled = 0)
           AND (IsActive = 1)
       )
       AND AccountID = 5025132 ORDER BY PlanType;
```

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` is your friend, number each row within a particular subscription partition and pick the first one per group.

Comment: Pretty much this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group